# Create a shared library for multiple applications for ARM cortex-m4

Tags: arm, embedded, keil, cortex-m

I'm trying to create project which contains a drivers library and two separate application (Booltloader + app), now I want to share the drives library between the two apps in order to save space on the flash...

I saw this [tutorial](https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/checksum-protected-library-using-iar-embedded-workbench-for-arm/) for IAR, but I must use Keil uvision5 and I didnt find anything helpful online.

Anyone can guide me through this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the code into three parts (bootloader, library, application) most likely is too much. I think it is better to combine the bootloader and the drivers in a single binary. While calling the application, the bootloader can provide information necessary to use the drivers.

A word of caution, though: a solution like this is way more tricky than just compiling the drivers in the application. Depending on the driver functions, there may be no true benefit on flash usage. In particular, if many drivers are not necessary, they will just occupy the flash instead of getting optimized-out.